# Find age from a birthdate stored in any type of format php

Tags: php

My client wants me to show a child's age using their birth date stored within mysql. My previous code didn't work for all formats, due to the site not limiting how the user can enter this date. Here is what I have so far, but I am having trouble figuring out how to check for the formats. They have birthdays in `mm/dd/yyyy`, `mm/dd/yy`, `dd/mm/yyyy`, `dd/mm/yy`, `Abbrev day, yy`, `Abbrev day, yyyy`. They also use different separators such as `.` or `-` which is easy enough to check for and use an explode.

```
$birthday=//data from db
$DOB=$birthday;

if(strpos($DOB,'/')){
  list($month,$day,$year)=explode('/',$DOB);
  if(strlen($year)=='4'){
    //year is in Y format
    $age = (date("md", date("U", mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, $day, $year))) > date("md") ? ((date("Y")-$year)-1):(date("Y")-$year));
  }else{
    if(strlen($month)=='4'){
      //format is adjusted using ymd - $month is actually the year, the $day is month, the $year is the day
      $age = (date("md", date("U", mktime(0, 0, 0, $day, $year, $month))) > date("md") ? ((date("Y")-$month)-1):(date("Y") -$month));
    }else{
      //year is in y format
      $age = (date("md", date("U", mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, $day, $year))) > date("md") ? ((date("y")-$year)-1):(date("y")-$year));
    }
  }
}elseif(strpos($DOB,'-')){
  list($month,$day,$year)=explode('-',$DOB);
  if(strlen($year)=='4'){
    //year is in Y format
    $age = (date("md", date("U", mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, $day, $year))) > date("md") ? ((date("Y")-$year)-1):(date("Y")-$year));
  }else{
    if(strlen($month)=='4'){
      //format is adjusted using ymd - $month is actually the year, the $day is month, the $year is the day
      $age = (date("md", date("U", mktime(0, 0, 0, $day, $year, $month))) > date("md") ? ((date("Y")-$month)-1):(date("Y") -$month));
    }else{
      //year is in y format
      $age = (date("md", date("U", mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, $day, $year))) > date("md") ? ((date("y")-$year)-1):(date("y")- $year));
    }
  }
}elseif(strpos($DOB,'.')){
  list($month,$day,$year)=explode('.',$DOB);
  if(strlen($year)=='4'){
    //year is in Y format
    $age = (date("md", date("U", mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, $day, $year))) > date("md") ? ((date("Y")-$year)-1):(date("Y")-$year));
  }else{
    if(strlen($month)=='4'){
      //format is adjusted using ymd - $month is actually the year, the $day is month, the $year is the day
      $age = (date("md", date("U", mktime(0, 0, 0, $day, $year, $month))) > date("md") ? ((date("Y")-$month)-1):(date("Y") -$month));
    }else{
      //year is in y format
      $age = (date("md", date("U", mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, $day, $year))) > date("md") ? ((date("y")-$year)-1):(date("y")- $year));
    }
  }
}else{}

echo $age;

}
```

Comment: how you deal with 03/03/1995? are you saved the format for each date?

Comment: Why will strtotime() not work?

Comment: @Akam, 03/03/1995 is March, 3rd anyway. :) But you're right in general, just used bad example. So, user2162686, what if you have 03/04/1995 stored? Is it MArch, 4th or April, 3rd? the only two ways to approach it is to (1) restirict formats allowed in DB (but not necessarily in UI) to only one or (2) store the format side-by-side with the date. What's better for your particular case - it's up to you to decide.

Comment: If you have both `mm/dd/yyyy` **and** `dd/mm/yyyy`... there will be errors, whichever way you may turn it. You can limit the damage, that's about it.

Comment: @Akam how will he deal with 01/02/03?

Comment: I am aware of this issue. I have adjusted the forms the original programmers created to make sure it stays in 1 format...mm/dd/yyyy. When the user logs in, they are notified to update their children's info including their dob. AS FOR the existing 01/02/03 until they get updated if it is this format 2 by 2 by 2 digits...act like its always mm/dd/yy.

Comment: I am going to tell my client that I can account for so much of this, but it cannot be perfect and full proof. I have thought about it. Would it be possible to simplify this. I tried using $variable=explode(Array('/','-','.'),$DOB); to eliminate the multiple elseifs, but I think i need to use preg_split due to explode not allowing the multiple deliminators

Answer (score 0):

The best you could hope to do is `strtotime()`.  So here is the code to figure out the age:

```
$birthday = // value from db
$birthdayTime = strtotime($birthday);

$age = date('Y') - date('Y', $birthdayTime);

if (date('md') < date('md', $birthdayTime)) {
    // we haven't reached their birthday this year so subtract one
    $age--;
}

echo $age;
```

What we do in the code. First we convert the string birthday to unix timestamp. At first thought one may want to subtract that timestamp from the current timestamp and divide by the number of seconds in a year but because that doesn't account for leap years and will cause funky results with birthdays around the end of February/beginning of March what we do is subtract the birth year from the current year and then check to see if we've had a birthday yet for the year. If we haven't then we subtract 1 and we get the age.

If your database allowed dd/mm/yy and mm/dd/yy it is 100% impossible to tell if 01/02/03 is January 2nd or February 1st. So you will have a few minor issues until you get your data fixed.

You could also try to make educated guesses mm/dd/yy is more of an American date format and dd/mm/yy is more of an everywhere-other-than-America date format so you can try and update the database data that way.